# SQL - JOIN TABLE A AND TABLE B SO THAT EACH ROW STATES WHICH TABLE IT COMES FROM, A, B OR BOTH

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, union

You have two tables A and B, both tables have the same columns but different rows, some rows exist in both table A and B, some rows only exist in table A or B but not both.
How can you join both tables so that the resulting table has all the rows from both tables and a new column that states where each row comes from, table A, table B, or BOTH.

EXAMPLE:

```
Table A
+------------+
| id | value |
+------------+
| 1  |   10  |
| 2  |   20  | 
+------------+

Table B
+------------+
| id | value |
+------------+
| 1  |   10  |
| 3  |   30  | 
+------------+

EXPECTED RESULT
+----------------------+
| id | value | origin  |
+----------------------+
| 2  |  20   |    A    |
| 3  |  30   |    B    |
| 1  |  10   |   BOTH  |
+----------------------+
```

I got asked this question on an interview and I didn't answer it properly so now I'm curious on what the correct answer is. Thanks in advance for answering my question, every little bit helps.

Comment: Start with a `UNION` of 2 queries that each adds the table name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can union the rows from both tables (with an added column indicating where each row came from) then `group by` and `group_concat(origin)` to check if the row exists in either or both tables:

```
select id, value, 
case group_concat(origin order by origin)
when 'A' then 'A'
when 'B' then 'B'
when 'A,B' then 'BOTH'
end as origin from
(select *, 'A' as origin from A
union all 
select *, 'B' as origin from B) t
group by id, value
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3c7f4ef232e5bc02ca686302b0a4ec32)

(Assuming a couple (id, value) cannot appear more than once in each table)